# How to make a button of this shape in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-button

[image]

how to make this background xml for a button.

Comment: in general you cannot do it in xml, you need to write a custom `Drawable` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use that `xml file`inside Drawable folder and assign it to TextView as `android:background="@drawable/xmlFile"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:radius="100dip"/>
    <solid
        android:color="#FFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#F00" />
    <padding
        android:left="6dip"
        android:right="6dip"
        android:top="5dip"
        android:bottom="5dip" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-layout-rounded-corner-border/

and

http://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/01/android-rounded-corners-button.html

Add a xml file in drawable folder and add this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<!-- view background color -->
<solid
    android:color="#a9c5ac" >
</solid>

<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#1c1b20" >
</stroke>

<!-- If you want to add some padding -->
<padding
    android:left="4dp"
    android:top="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:bottom="4dp"    >
</padding>

<!-- Here is the corner radius -->
<corners
    android:radius="10dp"   >
</corners>

</shape>
```

and for button change background to this xml as 
`android:background="@drawable/yourxml"`

Answer (score 0):

Create your button background on as a drawable resource like this.

**button_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#f5f5f5" />

            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
            <padding android:bottom="16dp" android:left="16dp" android:right="16dp" android:top="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false">
        <shape>

            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
            <padding android:bottom="16dp" android:left="16dp" android:right="16dp" android:top="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

Then simply use it on your button

```
<Button 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:text="Your Text"
   android:textColor="#FF0000"
   android:background="@drawable/button_background" />
```